# Who are the מאמ"ר and the כה"ח?

Tags: sources-mekorot, lulav-etrog-arba-minim, acronyms

I found a reference to turning the body when waving the lulav. The text reads

ויש נוהגים גם להפנות את הגוף לארבע רוחות (מאמ"ר יג; כה"ח צו).

What, please, is the meaning of the abbreviations used for the sources of this custom  מאמ"ר יג; כה"ח צו and are the sources available online?

I found the reference at https://ph.yhb.org.il/13-05-04/ (at the bottom of the page).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Ma'amar Mordechai can be found [here](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20231&st=&pgnum=626).

The Kaf HaChayim can be found [here](http://sefaria.org/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.651.96).