# Maamar Mordechai in Mishna Berurah

Tags: sources-mekorot, authorship, mishnah-berurah

Who is the author of the Maamar Mordechai quoted often in the Mishna Berurah.

There are quite a number of sefarim on HebrewBooks with that title and the old prints make it hard to scan through them to find a given quote.

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/95698/759

Answer (score 6, accepted):

His name is Rabbi Mordechai Karmi. You can read the [English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordecai_Karmi) and [Hebrew](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%93%D7%9B%D7%99_%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%99) Wikipedia articles on him here. The Hebrew article notes (correctly) that he is often cited by the Mishnah Berurah.